# Coretext make part of a nsmutableattributtedstring linkable

Tags: ios, core-text, nsattributedstring

Suppose i have a CoreText `NSMutableAttributedString` with this words:"Continue Reading"

I want to make the first word "Continue" clickable so that i can tap on it and show a load another `UIView`. I have found how to make it underlined and change the colour to blue but how can i make it linkable. Any example?

This is my code to make it underlined and the foreground colour blue.

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(string, CFRangeMake(0, 10),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
          SInt32 type = kCTUnderlineStyleSingle;

CFNumberRef underline = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &type);
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(string, CFRangeMake(0, text.length),kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName, underline);
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(string, CFRangeMake(0, text.length),kCTUnderlineColorAttributeName, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
```

Thanks

Comment: CoreText is purely a rendering technology. It doesn't handle interaction. If you need tappable words, you need to implement that yourself. There's probably a 3rd-party library out there that already does it though.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your interest...any examples please.

Comment: I'm sure you can use Google just as well as I can.

Comment: I am searching for over a month i just have found for making URL detect links any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of resources out there, one which is 
found here [Hyperlink in coretext](http://danielgorst.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/embedding-a-hyperlink-into-coretext/)

What you need to do is find the bounds of the word/section that you want to make clickable, and add a subview within those bounds that handles a tap. Hope it helps!